# How to superimpose views over each captured frame inside CVImageBuffer, realtime not post process

Tags: ios, swift, camera, core-graphics, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I have managed to setup a basic `AVCaptureSession` which records a video and saves it on device by using `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`. I have been searching through docs to understand how we can add statistics overlays on top of the video which is being recorded.

i.e.

[image]

As you can see in the above image. I have multiple overlays on top of video preview layer. Now, when I save my video output I would like to compose those views onto the video as well.

What have I tried so far?

- Honestly, I am just jumping around on internet to find a reputable blog explaining how one would do this. But failed to find one.
- I have read few places that one could render text layer overlays as described in [following post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) by creating `CALayer` and adding it as a sublayer.
- But, what about if I want to render `MapView` on top of the video being recorded. Also, I am not looking for screen capture. Some of the content on the screen will not be part of the final recording so I want to be able to cherry pick view that will be composed.

What am I looking for?

1. Direction.
2. No straight up solution
3. Documentation link and class names I should be reading more about to create this.

**Progress So Far:**

I have managed to understand that I need to get hold of `CVImageBuffer` from `CMSampleBuffer` and draw text over it. There are things still unclear to me whether it is possible to somehow overlay MapView over the video that is being recorded.

Comment: I would just try and dig a project which might be doing something similar https://github.com/search?l=Swift&p=5&q=CVImageBuffer+CMSampleBuffer+record&type=Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that helps you to achieve your goal is to use a `Metal` framework. Using a `Metal` camera is good for minimising the impact on device’s limited computational resources. If you are trying to achieve the lowest-overhead access to camera sensor, using a `AVCaptureSession` would be a really good start.

You need to grab each frame data from `CMSampleBuffer` (you're right) and then to convert a frame to a `MTLTexture`. `AVCaptureSession` will continuously send us frames from device’s camera via a delegate callback.

All available overlays must be converted to `MTLTextures` too. Then you can composite all `MTLTextures` layers with `over` operation.

So, here you'll find all necessary info in **four-part** [Metal Camera](https://navoshta.com/metal-camera-part-1-camera-session/) **series**.

And here's a link to a **blog**: [About Compositing in Metal](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2016/2/27/bloom-effect-in-metal.html).

Also, I'd like to publish code's excerpt (working with AVCaptureSession in Metal):

```
import Metal

guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
    // Handle an error here.
}

// Texture cache for converting frame images to textures
var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache?

// `MTLDevice` for initializing texture cache
var metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

guard
    let metalDevice = metalDevice
    where CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, metalDevice, nil, &textureCache) == kCVReturnSuccess
else {
    // Handle an error (failed to create texture cache)
}

let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

var imageTexture: CVMetalTexture?
let result = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache.takeUnretainedValue(), imageBuffer, nil, pixelFormat, width, height, planeIndex, &imageTexture)

// `MTLTexture` is in the `texture` variable now.
guard
    let unwrappedImageTexture = imageTexture,
    let texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(unwrappedImageTexture),
    result == kCVReturnSuccess
else {
    throw MetalCameraSessionError.failedToCreateTextureFromImage
}
```

> And here you can find a final project on a GitHub: [MetalRenderCamera](https://github.com/navoshta/MetalRenderCamera)

Comment: Please read the question again. My question is how to render overlayed views when we write video onto disk. This is more lower level api issue.

Comment: @TeaCupApp, now it's clear. I'll try to find the answer.

Comment: Yes, the new answer is what I just ended up drawing board after talking to my colleague. Good one mate! Once, this works expect a bounty on your way...

Comment: There is one more step to it, which is when we actually write video out with adaptor. I am creating a wrapper around the pipeline for open source. Also, GPUImage by Brad Larson was a big help understanding the pipeline from OpenGL perspective.

Comment: Nice to hear you did it))))

Comment: @TeaCupApp Please could you post how you composited the MTLTextures?